# The right usage of multiple EF 5.0 edmxs in a single solution

Tags: entity-framework, entity, edmx, edmx-designer

I'm following a database first approach in this example. Because of the manageability issue of a single edmx, I have decided to break down the single edmx to multiple edmxs.

I created a project and added a new ADO.net Entity Data Model called **AModel**. It gave me the option of Choosing DBNameEntities for **Save Entity connection string in the App.config**. As a result the context is generated as:

**public partial class *DBNameEntities* : DbContext**

Now I added another ADO.net Entity Data Model called **BModel**. I gave the option of selecting DBNameEntities1 as a connection string for 'Save Entity connection string in the App.config'. Since I have already a connecting string which I created for the **AModel**, I deselected the option for the connection string. Now the context for BModel is generated as (POCO entities generated from the T4 template):

**public partial class *Entities* : DbContext**

1. In a single project, is it okay to use multiple dbContexts (DBNameEntities, Entities) for multiple models?
2. Or In a single project, is it advisable to use only single dbContext but break down the models into many with different edmxs?
3. How can I use the same connection string called *DBNameEntities* for multiple models but at the same time create meaningful contexts. I wanted the context for *BModel* is generated as **BContext** and the context for *AModel* is generated as **AContext**. eg. **public partial class AContext : DbContext**
4. Is the right approach to solving my problem, **to create different projects and each project have a model** rather than using a single project to have multiple edmxs.

Share your ideas.

Comment: In VS2012 you can have multiple views of the same model. Maybe this would be easier than having multiple edmx files/projects?

Comment: I found out this link where the author is [talking about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/24/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-1.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) using multiple edmxs.